# Backup maven artifact before install?

Tags: maven-3

I'd like to be able to back up an existing artifact in a repo during the install phase?
Can I do this with maven?

Currently I am coding a xcopy in a bat file that calls mvn install, but I think there has to be a better way? 
Additionally, is there a way for me to determine via maven or a windows command prompt the maven repository location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get current repository location you can use [`mvn help:effective-settings`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-settings-mojo.html) help command to print all settings.

As for archiving artifacts before install, it goes against Maven ideology. Basically snapshot versions can be overwritten at any time and release versions must never change. Instead of updating release version you need to change version (e.g. increase it).

Comment: Thank you, any thoughts on how I should extract the xml string in a bat file, I'm wondering if I should use powershell...